# Best way to merge exclusive parametrization with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

This is probably duplicated, but I always wonder if there is a "simple" way to reduce tests with multiple settings where some of them are exactly the same but for a specific parameter combination. So far I haven't found a simple approach.
How would you combine the following test cases with pytest?

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("credentials", ["A", "B"])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("path", ["/path_1"])
def test_is_authorized_1(client, path, headers):
    response = client.get(path, headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 200

@pytest.mark.parametrize("credentials", ["A"])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("path", ["/path_2"])
def test_is_authorized_2(client, path, headers):
    response = client.get(path, headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 200

@pytest.mark.parametrize("credentials", [None])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("path", ["/path_1"])
def test_not_authorized_1(client, path, headers):
    response = client.get(path, headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 401

@pytest.mark.parametrize("credentials", ["B", None])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("path", ["/path_2"])
def test_not_authorized_2(client, path, headers):
    response = client.get(path, headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 401
```

I feel like I am repeating myself.
Is there a way to reduce the repeated code merging each test case?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the first two test cases, and the last two test cases by just adding them to the same list in your decorator.

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("credentials", ["A", "B"])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("path", ["/path_1", "/path_2"])
def test_is_authorized_1(client, path, headers):
    response = client.get(path, headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 200


@pytest.mark.parametrize("credentials", [None, "B"])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("path", ["/path_1", "/path_2"])
def test_not_authorized_1(client, path, headers):
    response = client.get(path, headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 401
```

Docs:

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/historical-notes.html#applying-marks-to-pytest-mark-parametrize-parameters

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in your example the case {credential=B, path=/path_2} asserts a 200, however in the question it asserts for 401 from the `not_authorized` group.

Comment: Well then you need to change the order of the parameteres to match your business logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can send `credentials`, `path` and `status` as parameters to a single test

```
def data_source():
    credentials = [["A", "B"], ["A"], [None], ["B", None]]
    paths = [["/path_1"], ["/path_2"], ["/path_1"], ["/path_2"]]
    statuses = [200, 200, 401, 401]
    for data in zip(credentials, paths, statuses):
        for creds in data[0]:
            yield creds, *data[1:]


@pytest.mark.parametrize(['credentials', 'path', 'status'], data_source())
def test_is_authorized(client, credentials, path, status, headers):
    response = client.get(path, headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == status
```

The parameters will be

```
A    ['/path_1'] 200
B    ['/path_1'] 200
A    ['/path_2'] 200
None ['/path_1'] 401
B    ['/path_2'] 401
None ['/path_2'] 401
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [pytest-cases](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-cases) I found out an interesting alternative:

```py
from pytest_cases import parametrize, parametrize_with_cases

class AuthorizedCases:

    @parametrize("headers", ["heads_A", "heads_B"])
    @parametrize("path", ["/path_1"])
    def case_path1(self, path, headers):
        return path, headers

    @parametrize("headers", ["heads_A"])
    @parametrize("path", ["/path_2"])
    def case_path2(self, path, headers):
        return path, headers


class UauthorizedCases:

    @parametrize("headers", [None])
    @parametrize("path", ["/path_1"])
    def case_path1(self, path, headers):
        return path, headers

    @parametrize("headers", ["heads_B", None])
    @parametrize("path", ["/path_2"])
    def case_path2(self, path, headers):
        return path, headers


@parametrize_with_cases("path, headers", cases=AuthorizedCases)
def test_is_authorized(client, path, headers):
    response = client.get(path, headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 200

@parametrize_with_cases("path, headers", cases=UnauthorizedCases)
def test_not_authorized(client, path, headers):
    response = client.get(path, headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 401
```

It is longer than the question code, but I think it has more flexibility for complex cases. It looks this is related to something called in pytest as "covariant parametrization". See [Parametrize based on another parameter
#4050](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4050) on github.